# JFX Images in Text

Tags: java, javafx

Is it possible to create multiple images within a paragraph of text in JavaFX2? For example, smileys in text.

Please note: I'm specifically asking for JavaFX2, NOT JavaFX8.

Comment: JavaFX 4? Don't know that, you mean Javafx 2?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't really place images inside a single [Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) node in JavaFX 2.

You could use Dingbats like fonts that have [smiley faces in them](http://www.dafont.com/search.php?q=smiley), but then you would still probably want to use multiple nodes to construct your paragraph, switching fonts back and forth between your regular font and the smiley font.

What you can do is use a [FlowPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html) with different Text and ImageView instances. You can find a sample of this approach in the related question: [Javafx Text multi-word colorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081892/javafx-text-multi-word-colorization).

I know you aren't interested in Java 8, but in case others are, in Java 8 you can you can use the [TextFlow](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) to style text rather than using a combination of different Text instances in a FlowPane.  TextFlow is more elegant as it will handle wrapping at word breaks automatically for you, whereas, with a FlowPane you will need to create a new Text node for every word to get smooth word wrapping of a paragraph.  Certainly, Java 8 is preferred for this kind of task.

Comment: Thanks. Plus 1'd. I am aware of TextFlow for JFX8, which is going to be awesome. I just wondered if there was a way with JFX2. I only want to use JFX8 when it's officially released.