# JavaFX change color of one word in a label

Tags: css, javafx

I am building a property management system for desktop and I am currently working on a payment feed feature.  I want the payment amount to be highlighted in a different color within my label to improve readability.

I have tried the following approach:

```
String datePaid  = "just now";
Label amount = new Label("350");
Label label2 = new Label("paid £" + amount.getText() + " " + datePaid);
```

I then tried to apply the following CSS

```
    amount.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #000 !important; -fx-highlight-text-fill: #000 !important; -fx-font-family: Arial");
    label2.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #fff; -fx-font-size: 14px; -fx-translate-x: -36; -fx-translate-y: 24; -fx-font-family: 'Open Sans Light'");
```

I thought by declaring `!important` I would override the styles applied in label2, but instead all text renders to the screen in #fff

How would I go about achieving the desired result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javafx Text multi-word colorization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081892/javafx-text-multi-word-colorization)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try using Text inplace of Label for amount. I hope it will fix the issue. You can directly apply color to the Text as well.

```
Text amount = new Text("350");
amount.setFill(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 5):

My solution for this was to use a [TextFlow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) pane:

```
TextFlow textFlowPane = new TextFlow();
Text redText = new Text("This is red text...");
redText.setFill(Color.RED);
Text greenText = new Text("followed by green text");
greenText.setFill(Color.GREEN);
textFlowPane.getChildren().addAll(redText, greenText);
```

[image: Red and green text with textFlow]